# Search Results saying "It appears the URL has been modified. Restore"

Tags: search

Has anyone seen this? In Google's search results I'm seeing "It appears the URL has been modified. Restore" under a bunch of my pages but that text does not exist on the page or in Google's cached version.

If you search for "It appears the URL has been modified. Restore" there are a bunch of sites affected. Can I safely assume this is a Google error?

Comment: What application are you using to generate your web pages?  It may well be that application creating the text.

Comment: nope, the text is not generated by my system and it doesn't appear in the source of the other results pages either.  The text is also not in Google's cached version.